# Difference between declaring methods in php 5.3 and 5.6

Tags: php

I am working on a codebase that runs on a live environment with php version 5.3.29.

I've tried moving it over to a test environment which uses php version 5.6.28.

I noticed that the `loadConfig` method doesn't get invoked but does if I declare it with the `private` keyword.

Is this a breaking change between version 5.3 and 5.6 where methods need declared with, private, public, protected etc?

This partial example class:

```
class BaseConfig  {
    var $dao = null;
    var $appConfig = array();
    var $frameworkBootstrap = null;
    var $reserved = array(CMD_PARAM, 'go', 'submit', 'xsubmit');

    function BaseConfig() {
        register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, '_doShutdown'));

        $this->frameworkBootstrap = parse_ini_file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . FRAMEWORK_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG);
        $this->loadConfig();
    }


    function loadConfig() {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ConfigDAO.class.php');

        $dao = new ConfigDAO();
        $this->appConfig = $dao->getAllSettings();
    }
}
```

These are the errors that are displayed:

`Strict Standards: Declaration of SimpleConfig::getInstance() should be compatible with & BaseConfig::getInstance($type = NULL)`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method SimpleConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically`

`Notice: Use of undefined constant CMD_PARAM - assumed 'CMD_PARAM'`

`Warning: parse_ini_file(www/conf/config.app.settings.ini.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

`Notice: Constant ADMIN_SAVE_QUANTITY_SHIPPING_CMD already defined`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Util::getSelf() should not be called statically`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Util::cleanUri() should not be called statically`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Util::getProtocol() should not be called statically`

`Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS`

`Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_URI`

`Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Request::getInstance()`

`Strict Standards: Declaration of MySQLQueryResult::getRow() should be compatible with QueryResult::getRow($index, $type)`

`Strict Standards: Declaration of MySQLDatabase::getInstance() should be compatible with Database::getInstance()`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Language::getInstance() should not be called statically`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BootstrapConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Warning: parse_ini_file(/var/www/conf/config.app.bootstrap.ini.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

`Deprecated: Non-static method MySQLDatabase::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::mysql_real_escape_string() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Session::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BootstrapConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method MySQLDatabase::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BootstrapConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::mysql_real_escape_string() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BeanMapper::populateBean() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Strict Standards: Declaration of ProductItem::getWeightAmount() should be compatible with Item::getWeightAmount($mult = true)`

`Strict Standards: Declaration of ProductItem::getSelectedOption() should be compatible with & Item::getSelectedOption()`

`Notice: Undefined index: digiShopCacheDisabled`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::santizeInput() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Notice: Undefined index: xdigiSHOPadminSale`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::santizeInput() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Notice: Constant CACHE_DISABLED already defined`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Session::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BootstrapConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BootstrapConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BaseConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method MySQLDatabase::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::mysql_real_escape_string() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method BeanMapper::populateBean() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Notice: Undefined index: adminStorefront`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::santizeInput() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::santizeInput() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Util::buildURL() should not be called statically`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Util::buildURL() should not be called statically`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method KeywordUtil::getKeywordSessionIdentifier() should not be called statically`

`Notice: Undefined index: digiSHOPkeywordSessionCookie`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::santizeInput() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::sanitize() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Deprecated: Non-static method Util::checkArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference`

`Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed`

Comment: When you don't add a visibility keyword (such as `public`, `private` or `protected`) a method will default to be public.

Comment: In this context it won't work then as `loadConfig` is being called within a class so, "privately".  Some of this code is ancient so its going to have this issue throughout a large codebase :(  That must be a difference in the versions as it works using php v5.3.

Comment: Public vs private is not your issue -- `loadConfig()` will always be callable from `BaseConfig()` regardless of its visibility, because it's in the same class. Perhaps the ConfigDAO class is using a feature that's been removed.

Comment: I've commented out the body of the `loadConfig()` function and replaced it with `echo "loadConfig";` and this only shows if I use the keyword `private`

Comment: That makes no sense. Turn on error logging and check your logs. If you're trying to invoke a class that is not visible to you, the logs will say so.

Comment: I turned on error logging and got loads of errors.  Looks like lots of code changes needed to get this to work on v5.6.

Comment: Your code is using the PHP/4 syntax so it's going to take some work to adapt it to PHP/5.6 but you don't need to fix all error messages at once. In fact, error messages tend to cascade and fixing one notice instance often fixes a dozen more.

Comment: It does work on php v5.3 on the live environment but yes it will take some work to update the code.  There is a lot of it too.